# DeepPtr: a deep-copying unique_ptr wrapper in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers

When using the pimple idiom it is necessary to represent your "impl" as a forward declared pointer in the header file.  This necessitates a lot of boilerplate code to implement the [rule of five](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4782757/2779792).

Instead, I want to wrap `std::unique_ptr` with a template class `DeepPtr` which automatically deep copies on copy construction, assignment, and "deep" swaps on move construction and move assignment.  The resulting class could also be convenient for "value-like" objects that need to be passed by handle due to polymorphism.

Areas of concern are:

- Correct use of the swap idiom (should the local swap function be `private`/`public` or done some other way)?
- Const correctness of the dereferencing operator overloads
- Signature of the assignment operator function (`const DeepPtr& other`) which uses this const ref only to copy to temp.  This seems strange, but correct.
- Any other pitfalls that could be caused by this class.

---

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

template <typename T>
class DeepPtr
{
public:
    DeepPtr() :myPtr( nullptr ) {}

    DeepPtr( const T& value ) :myPtr( new T{ value } ) {}

    DeepPtr( const DeepPtr& other )
    :myPtr( nullptr )
    {
        if ( other )
        {
            myPtr = std::unique_ptr<T>{ new T{ *other } };
        }
    }

    DeepPtr( DeepPtr&& other )
    :myPtr( nullptr )
    {
        if ( other )
        {
            myPtr = std::unique_ptr<T>{ new T{ *other } };
        }
    }

    DeepPtr& operator=( const DeepPtr& other )
    {
        DeepPtr temp{ other };
        swap( *this, temp );
        return *this;
    }

    DeepPtr& operator=( DeepPtr&& other )
    {
        swap( *this, other );
        return *this;
    }

    static void swap( DeepPtr& left, DeepPtr& right ) { std::swap( left.myPtr, right.myPtr ); }

    T& operator*() { return *myPtr; }

    const T& operator*() const { return *myPtr; }

    T* const operator->() { return myPtr.operator->(); }

    const T* const operator->() const { return myPtr.operator->(); }

    const T* const get() const { return myPtr.get(); }

    operator bool() const { return (bool)myPtr; }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<T> myPtr;
};
```

---

Comment: It's interesting that you want to be able to copy a unique_ptr which is designed to be unique, i.e., non-copyable. For my own curiosity, if you wanted to copy unique_ptr(s), wouldn't it be better to instead use a shared_ptr? What are the advantages of using a DeepPtr over a shared_ptr?

Comment: @BenJ: He happens to be holding the state of the object in a pointer (because he is using PIMPL). When he copies the object he wants to copy the state for the new object. If you use shared pointer then you are using shared state (thus it is not a copy). Thus mutating would affect both objects.

Comment: Self plug: I wrote a couple of blogs about writing smart pointers [here](http://lokiastari.com/blog/2014/12/30/c-plus-plus-by-example-smart-pointer/):

Comment: Shared pointers would shallow copy, but I want deep copy.

Comment: You probably do not want to use `{ }` to initialize your `new`ed object. This will call the initializer list constructor, if and when it is available. It means that if you have `T=std::container` this will (may?) behave differently than if T is a POD type, or something that does not define an initializer list constructor.

Comment: Since we are using C++ 11, you also do not want to define `swap`. You have Rule of 5, and you should be `move`ing not calling swap.

Comment: In fact I think you can get the copy and move assignement operators for free by passing the argument by *value* rather than distinguishing between `const T&` and `T&&`. In some cases this is not advisable. If I remember correctly for large objects distinguishing between them is a good optimization - but you will have to check that. I may not be able to find the info for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Pragma(s)

Pragma once (like all pragmas) is not supported by all compilers.

```
#pragma once
```

Prefer to use header guards.
You can generate a GUID or you can use the namespace and file name to make it unique.

### Namespace

You have not put your code into a namespace.

### Constructor nullptr

There are some situations where it is nice to be able to construct with an explicit `nullptr`.
[See here](http://lokiastari.com/blog/2015/01/23/c-plus-plus-by-example-smart-pointer-part-iii/)

```
    DeepPtr() :myPtr( nullptr ) {}
```

So you could modify this constructor slightly.

```
    DeepPtr(std::nullptr_t value = nullptr): myPtr(nullptr) {}
```

### Move Construction.

I though you said on move you wanted to move the object not copy it.

```
    DeepPtr( DeepPtr&& other )
    :myPtr( nullptr )
    {
        if ( other )
        {
            myPtr = std::unique_ptr<T>{ new T{ *other } };
        }
    }
```

This does a copy on move construction. Also you should mark you move constructor as `noexcept`. This will give you several advantages when using the object with STL containers (the STL will default to copy even if move is available if the move is not not marked noexcept. This is to provide the strong exception grantee).

Note: You should only mark it as noexcept if it will not throw. So you should not do that if you are going to copy only; if you change this to do an actual move then add `noexcept`.

### Copy and Swap

This is technically correct.

```
    DeepPtr& operator=( const DeepPtr& other )
    {
        DeepPtr temp{ other };
        swap( *this, temp );
        return *this;
    }
```

But you get a better optimization if you use passing by value to get your copy. Like this:

```
    DeepPtr& operator=(DeepPtr other)  // Pass by value gets copy
    {
        swap( *this, other );
        return *this;
    }
```

See [What is the copy-and-swap idiom?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3279543/14065)

### Move Assignment

Looks good. But like the move constructor, The move assignment should be marked as `noexcept`.

```
    DeepPtr& operator=( DeepPtr&& other )
    {
        swap( *this, other );
        return *this;
    }
```

### Swap

```
    static void swap( DeepPtr& left, DeepPtr& right ) { std::swap( left.myPtr, right.myPtr ); }
```

Missed the static first time threw. It is more normal to define a normal swap method. Then define a standalone swap function. Also like move operations the swap should be marked as noexcept.

```
    void swap(DeepPtr& other) noexcept {
        using std::swap;
        swap(*this.myPtr, other.myPtr);

           // Adding `using std::swap`
           // Then calling swap (without std::)
           // Is the normal way of doing this. As it allows for Koenig
           // look up of a type specific swap first. If that does not
           // exist then the std::swap version will be used by the compiler.
    }
};
// outside the class
void swap(DeepPtr& lhs, DeepPtr& rhs) noexcept {
    lhs.swap(rhs);
}
```

Now that I have done swap. I would change the move operators too:

```
    DeepPtr(DeepPtr&& other)    noexcept
        :myPtr( nullptr )
    {
        other.swap(*this);
    }
    DeepPtr& operator=( DeepPtr&& other ) noexcept
    {
        other.swap(*this);
        return *this;
    }
```

### Constness

```
    const T* const get() const { return myPtr.get(); }
```

Sure but are you only ever going to want a const version of the pointer. Like the last two operations `operator*` and `operator->` you probably want a symmetric non const version.

### Bool cast

You should mark this explicit.

```
    operator bool() const { return (bool)myPtr; }
```

See here https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/93353/507

Comment: Why use `swap` post C++ 11. `swap` is a C++ 03 thing.

Comment: @user3728501 can you give me more context on what your question is and the post C++11 alternative?

Comment: What would the advantage of using `swap` be over simply just using `move`. Assuming you don't use the by-value `operator=`, you would call `move` in place of `swap`. Then you can have all your constructors and `operator=` written in terms of a move instead of adding an extra swap function.

Comment: @user3728501 OK I see where you are going. Not sure I yet so why it is better though (yet). Do you have any articles (links) that dig into that and describe the advantages in detail (like implementation)?

Comment: My understanding that `swap` is a relic from pre - C++11 days, where in 03 it would be an optimization. (Swapping two things instead of copying a large block of memory.) However if my understanding is correct, post C++11 you want to do either an exchange (probably not though) or just a move. Put another way, what does swap provide here? Is it not another function which must be maintained, when it could have been removed and places where swap exists could be changed to `move`. Perhaps I labour the point too much?

Comment: I say "relic" because many still use the "swap ideom". Myself included until recently. There is a famous answer on SO which discusses copy-and-swap. (Maybe more than one.) But as far as I am aware these authors did not write these answers with a focus on C++11. Possibly the matter is still open debate and not settled, perhaps.

Comment: @user3728501 As I understand it. The simplest way to implement a move is to swap the values of two objects. Remember, the source of the move can be left in any state (as long as it is valid). The easiest "valid" state to leave is the state that was in the destination object. One reason this is useful is you don't have to release and then reacquire resources if you are going to reuse an object, if the object is not going to reuse the data it will usually be destroyed and release the resource with no extra work.

Comment: But if you have another mechanism that is better, I would love to read about it. Things are always open to debate (as long as by debate you mean "discussion with data").

Comment: @user3728501 `Myself included until recently.` What did you replace it with that works better? Do you have a link to an article that will describe the standard way you implement it and explain it so I can compare it. You keep saying "move" but you have not defined what that means. Without an understanding of how you do that (hence the request for an article ) it feels like you are just waving your hands vaguely saying this other technique is great. It could be better but how am I to compare with no specifics to compare to.

Comment: @user3728501 https://gist.github.com/Loki-Astari/14e1aa35d178843c300ad3bfeb0f877c

Comment: Instead of using `swap`, just call `move`. `swap` is slower (although who cares in the vast majority of cases, let's be real). You do not need to retain the data which you are swapping "in to". In other words `swap(A, B)`, you really want to do `A = move(B)`. Two reasons for this it's marginally faster (but who cares), but more importantly it states your actual intent, which is to get the data referenced by B to be referenced by A, ... as quickly as possible. You do not need to retain the data referenced by A.

Comment: If for some reason you do need to retain the data ... well I guess use swap. But to me this seems like a code smell, post C++ 11...

Comment: @user3728501 Is it faster? You don't provide any details, so impossible to tell. Is it a code smell? According to whom, you have not references any detailed discussion and again just made a claim. The intent argument is good, but what is the context. If I want to move I use `A = std::move(B)` to show intent (no need for a move method). Correct; you don't need to retain the data (state) for `A` but `B` must remain in a valid state.

Comment: @user3728501 In addition to making `move operations` and `copy assignment` trivial to write. You have to think that "swap" is a relatively standard function that is used by a bunch of standard algorithms. Now `std::swap()` will implement it using 3 move operations `t = std::move(l);l = std::move(r); r= std::move(t);`, but having a custom swap rather than relying on `std::swap()` is going to be more efficient.

Comment: @user3728501 extending that argument. If I look at the standard libraries. I see `swap()` being used extensively. Specifically: `Containers`, `Sorting`, `Smart Pointers`, `Ranges`, `Parallism`. Now they will all default to `std::swap` if you don't define one for your class, but why not provide a useful one that is explicit? Especially since it is also going to (in most cases) make implementing `move operation` and `copy assignment` trivial.

Comment: @user3728501 The reason I like define `move operations` and `copy assignment` in terms of the swap operations is because: 1) It is easy to write. 2) It makes the `move operations` trivial `noexcept` 3) It provides the `Strong Exception Gurantee` out of the box. 4) It is efficient (not claiming it is perfect). Sometimes it is not perfect, and you can argue for those on a case by case basis and implement custom `move construction` for them. But the `copy and swap idiom` is still the standard way of implementing `assignment` as it handles (both copy and move semantics in a single function).

Answer (score 6):

You already accepted Loki's answer (and he made good points) but there is one comment I wanted to add regarding this:

> •Any other pitfalls that could be caused by this class.

Your class has no information on the concrete type held within, causing slicing in the presence of derived classes;

Consider this scenario:

```
class Base { ... }; // not abstract (can be instantiated)
class Derived: public Base { ... };

auto ptr1 = DeepPtr<Base>(new Derived{});
auto ptr2 = ptr1;
```

The last line will populate ptr2 with a Base instance that has all the sliced values from ptr2's Derived instance (because ptr2's constructorr calls `new T`, which resolves to `new Base` - not `new Derived`).

You have two possible solutions for this:

- intrusive cloning (your class hierarchy rooted in Base needs to implement a `virtual Base* clone() = 0` where each specialization of Base returns it's own instance); this cloning implementation would be then used for deep copy;
- transparent cloning, based on template specialization of a factory function, by the derived type. I needed to implement something similar for the same reason (deep copy of polymorphic pointers). You can see [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/54371/polymorphic-owned-reference-wrapper-for-class-hierarchies) my implementation.

  See the use of `to_polymorphic` functions in my question, and how they instantiate the correct cloning function, transparently.

Comment: You can also store a Copier, like you can store a custom deleter in unique_ptr, to handle the copying. Construction needs to go through a make_deep_ptr which injects the proper copier without the use ever having to worry about it.

Answer (score 4):

> Edit: I'll leave this answer for completeness but you probably
>   shouldn't inherit from a smart pointer or be very careful when doing
>   so:
>   [is-it-ok-to-inherit-from-the-c11-smart-pointers-and-override-the-relative-oper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12539581/is-it-ok-to-inherit-from-the-c11-smart-pointers-and-override-the-relative-oper)

It seems to me like there's lot of code that simply wraps the functionality of the unique_ptr. Putting aside that having a copyable unique_ptr seems a bit dubious  (although it seems like a reasonable thing in this context) why don't we inherit from unique_ptr and provide the copy operators?

```
template <typename T>
struct pimpl_ptr : public std::unique_ptr<T>
{
    using std::unique_ptr<T>::unique_ptr;
    pimpl_ptr() {};
    pimpl_ptr(pimpl_ptr<T> const& other)
    { 
        auto value = *other.get();
        this->reset(new T(value));
    }
    pimpl_ptr<T>& operator=(pimpl_ptr<T> const& other)
    {
        auto value = *other.get();
        this->reset(new T(value));
        return *this;
    }
};
```

There's probably a handful of improvements that could be made, as per Loki Astari's answer, but I think conceptually this will do the same but in less lines of code.

Comment: Hi and welcome to CodeReview. There's no need for this to be a comment, it is a perfectly valid and useful answer.

Comment: Thank you Zak, I'll edit the comment out of the post since it's unnecessary.

Comment: You may also want to come and say hi in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor)

Comment: Not sure if auto automaticlly becomes a reference or an object. So you way want to be explicit in using a reference:  `auto const&` rather than `auto`

Comment: I hadn't considered inheritance.  Thank you for this.

Comment: The more I think about this, the more I think that using composition
and wrapping the smart pointer is the better solution. The use of inheritance seems to violate the is-a relationship. I.e. we can't really say
pimpl_ptr is a unique_ptr, because we changed the very definition of what  the unique_ptr is meant to do. This might just seem like semantics, but highlights to me that something isn't right. Inheritance here gives us
more for less effort but could expose some undesirable behaviour. Whereas composition won't give any behaviour unless it has been specifically defined.

Comment: The reason why you should *not* inherit stl types is because they do not always define a virtual destructor. This *may* be implementation dependent as well - hence why just because you can see your current working version of stdlib *might* define some particular destructor as virtual, in general, they *might* not. This is the reason why you should never inherit from these types. 1/2

Comment: 2/2: Think about it this way, the authors of stdlib have a choice to make: Make their classes with virtual desctructors (and hence make their memory footprint larger when this might be uneccessary) or make them non-virtual destructors. Usually the latter approach is taken and anyone who wants to inherit from them should define a wrapper class (Adapter Pattern) which does have a virtual destructor and forwards the required function calls to the standard library object.