# Deep-copyable unique_ptr wrapper with std::visit-like feature

Tags: c++, memory-management, c++17

I'm writing a simple wrapper for `std::unique_ptr`, which copies the pointed object when copied.

Unlike [this wrapper](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/103744/deepptr-a-deep-copying-unique-ptr-wrapper-in-c), it properly copies derived classes if 
`unique_ptr` points to a base class.

Also it supports a feature similar to `std::visit`, which is described below.

<sub>(As noted by @Quuxplusone, deep-copying feature resembles that of `std::any`.)</sub>

---

Here's a short description of my class.
**(The implementation is at the bottom of the question.)**

- It supports conventional `operator*`, `operator->`, `T* get()`, and `operator bool`.
- It doesn't have `.reset()`, but `my_obj = {};` can be used instead.
- Can be copy constructed/assigned. When copied, copies the underlying object.
- Can't aquire ownership of an external pointer, and can't release ownership of stored pointer.
- `std::make_unique`-esque construction: `DynStorage<T> my_obj = DynStorage<T>::make(…);`.
  Can be written as `DynStorage<T> my_obj(…);` if argument list is not empty.
  Example usage:

  ```
  auto x = DynStorage<int>::make(42);
  std::cout << x.get() << '\n'; // Prints 42
  ```
- `DynStorage<Derived>` *can't* be converted to `DynStorage<Base>` (to simplify the implementation).
  The only way to make a `DynStorage<Base>` that points to a derived class is to use `DynStorage<Base> my_obj = DynStorage<Base>::make<Derived>(…);`
- `const DynStorage<T>` doesn't allow you to modify the pointed object (unlike `unique_ptr`).
- Pointers to arrays aren't supported.
- Supports a feature similar to `std::visit`, but you have to specify every possible visitor function in advance in an (optional) template parameter of `DynStorage`:

  ```
  // Assume we have some classes:
  struct A {virtual ~A() {}};
  struct B : A {};

  // Some overloaded (or template) function:
  void foo(A) {std::cout << "foo(A)\n";}
  void foo(B) {std::cout << "foo(B)\n";}

  // And we want to call a correct overload on a pointed object:
  int main()
  {
      auto x = DynStorage<A>::make(); // Makes an instance of A
      auto y = DynStorage<A>::make<B>(); // Makes an instance of B
      foo(*x); // Prints foo(A)
      foo(*y); // Prints foo(A), but we want foo(B)
  }

  // Here is how we do that:
  template <typename BaseT>
  struct MyFuncsBase : DynamicStorage::func_base<BaseT>
  {
      virtual void call_foo(BaseT *) = 0;
      using Base = MyFuncsBase;
  };

  template <typename BaseT, typename DerivedT>
  struct MyFuncs : MyFuncsBase<BaseT>
  {
      void call_foo(BaseT *base) override
      {
          foo(*DynamicStorage::derived<DerivedT>(base));
      }
  };

  int main()
  {    
      auto x = DynStorage<A,MyFuncs>::make();
      auto y = DynStorage<A,MyFuncs>::make<B>();

      x.functions().call_foo(x.get()); // prints foo(A)
      y.functions().call_foo(y.get()); // prints foo(B)
  }
  ```

---

#### The implementation

**`dynamic_storage.h`**

```
#ifndef DYN_STORAGE_H_INCLUDED
#define DYN_STORAGE_H_INCLUDED

#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

namespace DynamicStorage
{
    namespace impl
    {
        // Type trait to check if A is static_cast'able to B.
        template <typename A, typename B, typename = void> struct can_static_cast_impl
            : std::false_type {};
        template <typename A, typename B> struct can_static_cast_impl<A, B,
            std::void_t<decltype(static_cast<B>(std::declval<A>()))>> : std::true_type {};
        template <typename A, typename B> inline constexpr bool can_static_cast_v =
            can_static_cast_impl<A,B>::value;

        // Type trait to check if A is dynamic_cast'able to B.
        template <typename A, typename B, typename = void> struct can_dynamic_cast_impl
            : std::false_type {};
        template <typename A, typename B> struct can_dynamic_cast_impl<A, B,
            std::void_t<decltype(dynamic_cast<B>(std::declval<A>()))>> : std::true_type {};
        template <typename A, typename B> inline constexpr bool can_dynamic_cast_v =
            can_dynamic_cast_impl<A,B>::value;

        template <typename A, typename B>
        inline constexpr bool can_static_or_dynamic_cast_v =
            can_static_cast_v<A,B> || can_dynamic_cast_v<A,B>;

        template <typename T> T *get_instance()
        {
            static T ret;
            return &ret;
        }
    }

    // Downcasts a pointer. Attempts to use static_cast, falls back
    // to dynamic_cast. If none of them work, fails with a static_assert.
    template <typename Derived, typename Base> Derived *derived(Base *ptr)
    {
        static_assert(impl::can_static_or_dynamic_cast_v<Base*, Derived*>,
                      "Pointer to derived can't be obtained from pointer to base.");
        if constexpr (impl::can_static_cast_v<Base*, Derived*>)
            return static_cast<Derived *>(ptr); // This doesn't work if base is virtual.
        else
            return dynamic_cast<Derived *>(ptr);
    }

    template <typename B> struct func_base
    {
        using Base = func_base;
        virtual std::unique_ptr<B> copy_(const B *) = 0;
    };

    template <typename B, typename D> struct default_func_impl : func_base<B> {};

    template
    <
        typename T,
        template <typename,typename> typename Functions = default_func_impl
    >
    class DynStorage
    {
        static_assert(!std::is_const_v<T>, "Template parameter can't be const.");
        static_assert(!std::is_array_v<T>, "Template parameter can't be an array.");

        template <typename D> struct Implementation : Functions<T,D>
        {
            static_assert(impl::can_static_or_dynamic_cast_v<T*, D*>,
                          "Pointer to derived can't be obtained from pointer to base.");
            std::unique_ptr<T> copy_(const T *ptr) override
            {
                return ptr ? std::make_unique<D>(*derived<const D>(ptr))
                           : std::unique_ptr<T>();
            }
        };

        using Pointer = std::unique_ptr<T>;
        using FuncBase = typename Implementation<T>::Base;

        FuncBase *funcs = impl::get_instance<Implementation<T>>();
        Pointer ptr;

      public:
        // Makes a null pointer.
        DynStorage() noexcept {}

        // Constructs an object of type T from a parameter pack.
        template <typename ...P, typename = std::void_t<decltype(T(std::declval<P>()...))>>
        DynStorage(P &&... p) : ptr(std::make_unique<T>(std::forward<P>(p)...)) {}

        DynStorage(const DynStorage &other)
            : funcs(other.funcs), ptr(funcs->copy_(other.ptr.get())) {}
        DynStorage(DynStorage &&other) noexcept
            : funcs(other.funcs), ptr(std::move(other.ptr)) {}

        DynStorage &operator=(const DynStorage &other)
        {
            ptr = other.funcs->copy_(other.ptr.get());
            funcs = other.funcs;
            return *this;
        }
        DynStorage &operator=(DynStorage &&other) noexcept
        {
            ptr = std::move(other.ptr);
            funcs = other.funcs;
            return *this;
        }

        // Constructs an object of type T (by default)
        // or a derived type from a parameter pack.
        template <typename D = T, typename ...P,
                  typename = std::void_t<decltype(D(std::declval<P>()...))>>
        [[nodiscard]] static DynStorage make(P &&... p)
        {
            static_assert(!std::is_const_v<D>, "Template parameter can't be const.");
            static_assert(!std::is_array_v<D>, "Template parameter can't be an array.");
            static_assert(std::is_same_v<D,T> || std::has_virtual_destructor_v<T>,
                          "Base has to have a virtual destructor.");
            DynStorage ret;
            ret.ptr = std::make_unique<D>(std::forward<P>(p)...);
            ret.funcs = impl::get_instance<Implementation<D>>();
            return ret;
        }

        [[nodiscard]] explicit operator bool() const {return bool(ptr);}

        [[nodiscard]]       T *get()       {return ptr.get();}
        [[nodiscard]] const T *get() const {return ptr.get();}

        [[nodiscard]]       T &operator*()       {return *ptr;}
        [[nodiscard]] const T &operator*() const {return *ptr;}

        [[nodiscard]]       T *operator->()       {return *ptr;}
        [[nodiscard]] const T *operator->() const {return *ptr;}

        FuncBase &functions() const {return *funcs;}
    };

}

using DynamicStorage::DynStorage;

#endif
```

---

Some thoughts:

- It seems to work, but I'm not sure if I handle all possible exceptions correctly.
- I don't like the visiting syntax (especially visitor definitions), but I'm not sure how to improve it.
- It seems that copying (and visiting) could be optimized a bit by using function pointers instead of virtual functions, but I'm not sure how to do it elegantly.

Comment: ⟪It seems to work, but I'm not sure if I handle all possible exceptions correctly.⟫  Try multiple base classes and virtual base classes.  Try non-public base classes, and multiple copies of the same base class among the ancestors.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but this "`unique_ptr`, but copyable, and can hold any derived type, and can be visited via RTTI" smells an *awful lot* like `std::any`. Consider recasting your question (and your intuition about the desired behaviors of your class) in terms of a "visitable `std::any`."

Comment: @JDługosz Multiple bases and virtual bases seem to work. Non-public bases and duplicate bases produce compile-time errors, as expected. (But the errors are ugly, I'll add proper `static_assert`s.)

Comment: @Quuxplusone I guess you're right, it's similar to a visitable `std::any`. I decided to present it as `unique_ptr`-like class because stored types are restriced to classes derived from a common base, and it's possible easily get a pointer to that common base (which makes it different from `std::any`, and I want to keep this behaviour). I think I'll leave the question mostly unchanged, but add a note about it resembling `std::any`.

Answer (score 3):

That's really neat! I really like the idea of provoking the on-demand instantiation of the polymorphic dispatcher by passing it as a template template parameter.

That being said, I agree with you that the dispatching syntax can be improved quite a bit.

```
x.functions().call_foo(x.get()); // Yuck!
```

How about something that looks more like a proper visitor:

```
visit(x, &MyFuncsBase::call_foo);
```

This can work because pointers to member functions can be dispatched polymorphically. Here's a rough outline of how i'd go about pulling that syntax off:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, template<typename> typename DispatcherT>
class DynStorage {
  using base_dispatcher = typename DispatcherT<T>::base_t;

  struct StorageBase {
    public:
      virtual ~StorageBase() {}
      virtual T* getData() = 0;
      virtual base_dispatcher* getDispatcher() = 0;
  };

  template<typename U>
  struct StorageImpl : public StorageBase {
    U data_;
    static DispatcherT<U> dispatcher_;

    public:
      base_dispatcher* getDispatcher() override {
        return &dispatcher_;
      }

      T* getData() override {
          return &data_;
      }
  };

  std::unique_ptr<StorageBase> storage_;

public:
  DynStorage(std::unique_ptr<StorageBase> s) : storage_(std::move(s)) {}

  template<typename R, typename... argsT>
  R dispatch(R(base_dispatcher::*func)(T const&, argsT...), argsT... args) const {
    return (storage_->getDispatcher()->*func)(*storage_->getData(), args...);
  }

  template<typename U=T>
  static DynStorage make() {return DynStorage(std::make_unique<StorageImpl<U>>()); }
};

template<typename T, template<typename> typename DispatcherT, typename CB_T, typename... argsT>
decltype(auto) visit(DynStorage<T, DispatcherT> const& x, CB_T cb, argsT... args ) {
  return x.dispatch(cb, args...);
}

struct A {};
struct B : public A {};

struct MyFuncsBase {
  // no need for a virtual destructor
  virtual void foo(A const& val) = 0 ;
  virtual int bar(A const& val, float v ) = 0;
};

template<typename T>
struct MyFuncs : public MyFuncsBase {
  using base_t = MyFuncsBase;

  void foo(A const& val) override {
    std::cout << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
  }

  int bar(A const& val, float v ) override {
    return 0;
  }

};

int main()
{    
    auto x = DynStorage<A, MyFuncs>::make();
    auto y = DynStorage<A, MyFuncs>::make<B>();

    visit(x, &MyFuncsBase::foo);
    visit(y, &MyFuncsBase::foo);

    // Ooooh, arguments and return type support too!
    int res = visit(y, &MyFuncsBase::bar, 12.0f);
    return 0;
}
```

Obviously, this needs some cleanup, some proper forwarding semantics, etc... It's just here to demonstrate how the better syntax can be implemented.

**Edit:**

I also really dislike that universal singleton:

```
template <typename T> T *get_instance()
{
    static T ret;
    return &ret;
}
```

Not only is it unnecessary, but it also brings a hefty amount of per-call overhead.

You are also coding way too defensively for my taste. all of these `can_static_cast` and `can_dynamic_cast` are all redundant with the checks that the compiler performs when assigning values to `ptr`.

If you want to provide users with clearer errors when they mess up, then a simple `std::is_base_of<>` will suffice.

similarly, the following is perfectly fine for the users to do:

```
void call_foo(BaseT *base) override
{
    foo(static_cast<DerivedT*>(base));
}
```

So that `derived<>()` member function seems like extra api surface for no reason.

Comment: About `get_instance`: Good point, I'll replace it with a static object in `DynStorage<T>::Implementation`. About the `derived<>()`: The intent was to make an universal downcasting function, since `static_cast` doesn't work with virtual bases. About the alternative visiting syntax: Looks interesting, but the downside is that it requires writing `MyFuncsBase::` each time. I guess I need to think what do I like more.

Comment: You could make an argument that a universal downcaster is a potentially useful tool in general, but I see it as something orthogonal. I think you should just make a `down_cast<>` template function as a complete separate library/feature, and limit `DynStorage` to only performing the work it's supposed to do.

Comment: `func_base::copy_` requires `derived<>()` to function properly, but maybe I should put it into a separate header indeed.